# Azure Service Bus: Renew message lock token in Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azureservicebus

I'm working on an Azure Logic App which a Service Bus peek-lock trigger. The Service Bus has a message lock duration of 5 minutes.

When an instance is running for more than 5 minutes, the message lock will be released and I cannot complete the message in this case.

Since the logic app has introduced a new action for renewing the lock token ([image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwQd7.png]), I want to implement a renew lock token mechanism so that if the instance is running for more than 5 minutes, it will be automatically triggered to renew the lock token so that the message can be completed later on.

In short, I want the instance for a message is running for more than 5 minutes.

How can I achieve this? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the Logic App workflow with the Renew message lock token in Logic App

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I also found the thread you talk about in your answer. But now the logic app has an action of renewing the lock token itself. I think we can make use of this action with something like a counter for it. https://i.imgur.com/CVOPzsZ.png

Comment: Updated the answer with the Auto Renew Message Lock token

Comment: If my answer is helpful could you please accept my answer so that it would be helpful for other community members who face similar kind of issues

Comment: It seems like you have 2 complete message actions in your logic app. Can you explain what you will do to achieve this? Which part will be used for doing logic before completing the message?